# How do I create a "custom protocol" and map it to an application?

Tags: c#, windows, protocols

How would one go about creating a "custom protocol?" I know you can create a URL protocol by adding a number of registry entries to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, but that seems to only work in a browser. I need for it to work in Windows Explorer also.

I know that I can write a client/server sort of interface, but I think that is overkill for my client's needs (and budget).

Long story short...

- A third-party application should call: `tbwx:<row_id>`
- My app should load and delete a record from the database.

It sounds fairly simple (or so I thought). Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked into socket level programing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a custom protocol as long as you add a `URL Protocol` value of type `REG_SZ` to a class's key.  It doesn't need an actual value, just needs to be present.  Here's a simple example of an "Echo Protocol" I just created which works in Windows Explorer.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\echo]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="Echo Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\echo\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\echo\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\echo\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE /Q /C (echo %1) && pause"
```

Then if you type in Windows Explorer (or Run menu) for the path:

[image]

[image]

It should even work from a browser as well, you'll just need to confirm like any other protocol:
[image]
[image]

It should run the command:

[image]

I've found it will also work in the keys `HKCR` and `HKLM\Software\Classes` too.

Comment: That was exactly as far as I got. That works just fine in IE, but doesn't work at all in Windows Explorer. I want to be able to simply call my protocol (and have it in turn call my app) without having to call it through IE.

Comment: I don't know what to say then.  "It works on my machine."  (Windows 7 Pro x64)  Are you running this on 7 too?  Does the above work for you?

Comment: Yup. I'm using 7 Ultimate x64. How exactly are you calling echo? The reason I ask is because echo is actually a DOS command, so it would return something if typed into the cmd prompt or even when you type into the start menu (depending on how your %PATH% var is set up). You prolly already knew this, but I wanted to double check because I've been beating my head against the wall half of the night.

Comment: With the "Echo Protocol" installed, I just went into the explorer and typed `echo:foo` and it prints out `echo:foo` and pauses.  I called `echo` through `cmd.exe` instead since I couldn't call it directly.  Also I was originally testing the "Txt Protocol" which was supposed to open a file in notepad.  It didn't work because it always leaves the protocol name in the argument and I didn't want to deal with the string manipulation to open the file.

Comment: Ahh...one can never be too sure. I was just making sure you weren't forgetting to include the colon after echo. Some "genius" on another site was swearing up & down you don't need it. lol. At any rate, you were right, it works just fine, just as it did when I started coding two three days ago. Google Desktop was intercepting what I typed, didn't recognize it & popped up a search box. :| I tried it on another computer w/o Google Desktop on it and had no problems.

Comment: Ah that would explain it.  Glad to see you figured it out.  ;)

Comment: @JeffMercado is there any way to pass the foobar! to a running instance of the echo?

Comment: @MahdiHesari Not to my knowledge using Windows' builtin stuff., you'll have to build your own solution into the app itself or some launcher. Many ways this could be achieved, just need a way to identify that an instance is running and provide a way to send the desired message to that instance.

Answer (score 5):

The [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx) article details the process. There is a [utility](https://github.com/binki/CustomURL) on GitHub that can be used to register custom URL protocols. The source code is provided.