# TFS web portal: Possible to link/URI directly to line number in file?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

I would like to send my coworkers a link directly to a line number in a file in our TFS repo. Is this possible? If so, how? We are using TFS 2015.

---

Currently, the best way I have found is to link to the file like so:

> http[s]://{TFS-SERVER}[:{PORT}]/tfs/{PROJECT-COLLECTION}/_versionControl#path={PATH-TO-FILE}

Then, Ctrl+G to manually enter the line number. Before I dig through the JavaScript to find how Ctrl+G works, I am hoping someone can help me out.

---

I have tried variations on this theme, but without sucecss:

> http[s]://{TFS-SERVER}[:{PORT}]/tfs/{PROJECT-COLLECTION}/_versionControl#path={PATH-TO-FILE}#line={LINE}

---

P.S. My issue is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283458/share-a-link-to-a-location-in-code-source-file-line-number-in-visual-studio) but rather than for Visual Studio, I am looking for a link via the TFS web portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just heard from a guy inside of Microsoft that adding `&line=5`should work. My local tests show it only works for Visual Studio team Services and doesn't work on TFS 2015 update 2. You'll probably have to wait until update 3 for this feature to hit TFS.

In the mean time, the JavaScript simply looks for a div with the right linenumber attribute:

```
<div linenumber="5">...</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Once you select a piece of code in VSO code editor, it is possible to copy a link to that section (see picture below). It looks like TFS has pretty similar url structure, maybe it will work.

**Generated link structure**

> https://{PROJECT_URL}/_versionControl?path={FILE_PATH}&line={SELECTION_START_LINE}&lineEnd={SELECTION_END_LINE}&lineStartColumn={SELECTION_START_COLUMN}&lineEndColumn={SELECTION_END_COLUMN}

---

[image: vso code editor]