# Can I register a custom URL scheme without Administrator elevation?

Tags: url, wix, installation

There are many stack overflow questions about how to register a custom URL scheme (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows?rq=1)). However, the answer in every case seems to be to write to the privileged registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. My (wix-based) installer currently runs without elevation, installing per-user. Is there any way I can register a custom URL scheme *without* elevating to administrator privileges? I don't need to support anything older than Windows 7.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have links on a web page that perform specific actions in my application. My application is mostly .NET. The web page is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964401/385094) to a similar question. As an alternative to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, put the appropriate registry keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. This location does not require elevation to write to.