# Hyperlinks in Skype for business - On Premise

Tags: c#, skype, chatbot, skype-for-business, ucma

We are trying to use skype for business as a frontend for chatbot. The conversations will have hyperlinks in them which should generate some events when clicked.

Is there any way that can be handled in an on-click event, as of now when we click any hyperlink it is opened in a webbrowser.

Is there anyway to handle this in UCMA-5.0 SDK?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964152/HOW-DO-I-CREATE-A-CUSTOM-PROTOCOL-AND-MAP-IT-TO-AN-APPLICATION) help?

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible, as the "click" event occurs inside the Skype for Business client (so it happens on the client side) and there is nothing sent by the Skype for Business client when a user clicks on a link in an instant message.
There is nothing that could potentially be received on the UCMA-server side to determine that the user clicked on a certain link.

But you could, depending on your needs:

- detect the fact that the user clicked on the link by implementing something in the page that will be opened by the browser
- implement a "contextual data" channel that would open a CWE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/lync-conversation-window-extension) and you could implement your buttons and the related logic inside the CWE, and send the user input back using contextual data
- propose to the user to "Press 1 for this, Press 2 for that,..."